# What's the easiest way to get a perfect Genocide Route?

Tags: undertale

I have gotten the Neutral & True Pacifist endings but can't get the Genocide Route because I thought it would be harder than the True Pacifist. What's the easiest way to get a perfect Genocide run?

Answer (score 5):

Basically, genocide is 'easy'. You run through every screen, and those where there are random encounters, you do them until your random encounters say 'but nobody came'.

There's basically a fixed number of encounters every screen, and when you exhausted them all, you can move on.

Of what I heard, genocide is actually easier because the random fights are not that hard. But the final boss is the hardest in the game, by far.